# Is there a way to automatically adjust EQ settings when the audio output changes?

Tags: macos, audio, software-recommendation, music, automation

I have particular EQ settings I like to use for my speakers at home, however when I'm using my laptop speakers or Bluetooth headphones I prefer to have a flat EQ.  Is there a way to specify different EQ settings for each audio output and automatically switch to the correct setting when the audio output is changed?

Comment: Are you looking to use Automator to script your mouse - select the are output - select the application (presumably iTunes) then select the EQ? That all should be doable with Apple's automation tools.

Comment: Thanks, I realised that adjusting just the iTunes EQ would probably be sufficient for my needs, which is simple to adjust from AppleScript.

Comment: Great question - and even better answer - +1 all around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the current audio output gives "Built-in Output" for both headphones and internal speakers, however we need to be able to tell between headphones and speakers.  In order to do this, you can use code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14490863/618502) to create a program that checks whether headphones are plugged in or another audio output is in use:

```
#include <CoreAudio/CoreAudio.h>
#include <iostream>

void updateEQ() {
    AudioDeviceID defaultDevice = 0;
    UInt32 defaultSize = sizeof(AudioDeviceID);

    const AudioObjectPropertyAddress defaultAddr = {
        kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice,
        kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
        kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster
    };

    AudioObjectGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &defaultAddr, 0, NULL, &defaultSize, &defaultDevice);

    AudioObjectPropertyAddress property;
    property.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyDataSource;
    property.mScope = kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput;
    property.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;

    UInt32 dataSourceId = 0;
    UInt32 dataSourceIdSize = sizeof(UInt32);

    AudioObjectGetPropertyData(defaultDevice, &property, 0, NULL, &dataSourceIdSize, &dataSourceId);

    if (dataSourceId == 'hdpn') {
        std::cout << "Changed to headphones" << std::endl;
        system("osascript <<path to speaker EQ script>>");
    } else {
        std::cout << "Changed to not headphones" << std::endl;
        system("osascript <<path to other EQ script>>");
    }
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    updateEQ();
    return 0;
}
```

Each EQ script is then a simple AppleScript script that updates iTunes's EQ, for example the speaker EQ script is:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set current EQ preset to (get first EQ preset whose name is "Speakers")
    set EQ enabled to true
end tell
```